# Pulling text from json formatted block in javascript

Tags: javascript, format

I have a variable "link" that outputs this api sourced json formatted text as the following:

```
  [{
    breeds: [],
    id: '322',
    url: 'https://cdn2.thecatapi.com/images/322.jpg',
    width: 600,
    height: 400
  }]
```

I'm having trouble on pulling out just the url. What is the correct syntax for this?

```
console.log(link.url)
```

outputs as undefined.

Comment: How to you access an index in an array?

Answer (score 1):

If there is only one item returned you could use...

```
link[0].url
```

This API is returning an array and this example shows you how to retrieve the first element in your example.

Answer (score 0):

Traverse the array and access the required property. Access it by **link[index].propertyName**.

```js
link = [
  {
    breeds: [],
    id: "322",
    url: "https://cdn2.thecatapi.com/images/322.jpg",
    width: 600,
    height: 400,
  },
];
for (let i = 0; i < link.length; i++) {
  console.log(link[i].url);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your array has one or more objects your can iterate through your array with .map() and return the url of each one.

```js
arr = [{
  breeds: [],
  id: '322',
  url: 'https://cdn2.thecatapi.com/images/321.jpg',
  width: 600,
  height: 400
},{
  breeds: [],
  id: '323',
  url: 'https://cdn2.thecatapi.com/images/322.jpg',
  width: 600,
  height: 400
},{
  breeds: [],
  id: '324',
  url: 'https://cdn2.thecatapi.com/images/323.jpg',
  width: 600,
  height: 400
}]

arr.map((el) => console.log(el.url));
```